# How to fix error "\caption outside of float"

Tags: captions

here is my code:

```
\subsubsection{Example 1}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{l | c | c }
Fib. Num. & $3x+5$ & Convergence\\
\hline
Fn 0 & 5 &  \\
Fn 1 & 8 & 1.6\\
Fn 2 & 8 & 1\\
Fn 3 & 11 & 1.375\\
... & ... & ...\\
Fn 48 & 14422580933 & 1.618033988\\
Fn 49 & 23336226152 & 1.618033989\\
Fn 50 & 37758807080 & 1.618033989
\end{tabular}

\caption{Example 1: Data for polynomial with a power of 1}
\end{center}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: How would you like the string `Example 1: Data for polynomial with a power of 1` to be typeset? Please advise.

Comment: You can load the `caption` package and say `\captionof{table}{Example 1: Data for polynomial with a power of 1}` instead of `\caption{...}`.  Or, if you want the `tabular` to float around possibly to the next page of the document, you could place `\begin{table}[ht]` before the `\begin{center}` and place `\end{table}` after the `\end{center}`.  If you choose the latter option, I would replace the `center` environment with a simple `\centering`.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `\caption` can only be called inside a "float" (an object that TeX can float and relocate in your document, based on available spacing).  Therefore, you have two options.  If you want the table fixed at the particular location (let's say between two particular paragraphs, then you can, instead of `\caption{...}`, use `\captionof{table}{...}`, which is available with the `caption` package.

The second alternative is to place your `tabular` and `\caption` inside a "float", the logical one in this case being the `table` environment.   Thus, enclose your code between `\begin{table}[ht]...\end{table}`.  The `[ht]` option tells TeX to try to place the table `h`ere, but if unable, place it at the `t`op of a nearby page that follows.  I also, for this case, replaced the `center` environment with the `\centering` macro, because both `table` and `center` introduce vertical space, whereas `\centering` does not.

Finally, I relocated the captions above the `tabular`, just out of standard convention.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption,lipsum}

\begin{document}
\subsubsection{Example 1}

\lipsum[4]
\captionof{table}{Example 1: Data for polynomial with a power of 1}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{l | c | c }
Fib. Num. & $3x+5$ & Convergence\\
\hline
Fn 0 & 5 &  \\
Fn 1 & 8 & 1.6\\
Fn 2 & 8 & 1\\
Fn 3 & 11 & 1.375\\
... & ... & ...\\
Fn 48 & 14422580933 & 1.618033988\\
Fn 49 & 23336226152 & 1.618033989\\
Fn 50 & 37758807080 & 1.618033989
\end{tabular}

\end{center}
 
\lipsum[4]

\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\captionof{table}{Example 1: Data for polynomial with a power of 1}
\begin{tabular}{l | c | c }
Fib. Num. & $3x+5$ & Convergence\\
\hline
Fn 0 & 5 &  \\
Fn 1 & 8 & 1.6\\
Fn 2 & 8 & 1\\
Fn 3 & 11 & 1.375\\
... & ... & ...\\
Fn 48 & 14422580933 & 1.618033988\\
Fn 49 & 23336226152 & 1.618033989\\
Fn 50 & 37758807080 & 1.618033989
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

[image]